# Writing my own compareToIgnoreCase method

Tags: java, arrays, string

So I've looked around for a similar question for a day or two now and it seems like this is a new topic. For a little project, I'm trying to hand write my own compareToIgnoreCase() method without using the API for strings. In the program, the user enters a string and the class definition converts the string to a char array. The user will enter another string and it will compare it to the first string entered. Here is my `compareTo()` method I wrote. My question is, how would I edit this to ignore the case while comparing.

```
public int compareTo(MyString anotherMyString) {
    if(anotherMyString.sequence[i] > 0) {
        return 1;
    } else if(anotherMyString.sequence[i] == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're missing a loop or recursion somewhere, given that the `i` variable is declared nowhere

Comment: Is using the API for `Character` ok? Do you need to support all Unicode letters, or just the A-Z letters?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're ok with using `java.lang.Character`, one possible solution to ignore case is to convert each char to lowercase before comparing them:

```
char1 = Character.toLowerCase(char1);
char2 = Character.toLowerCase(char2);

// compare char1, char2
```

Comment: Question said *"without using the API for strings"*. I would consider using the API for *character* would be off-limit too, but I guess only OP can say that for sure *([I've posted that question to OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45310354/writing-my-own-comparetoignorecase-method#comment77583121_45310354))*.

Comment: I assumed he just didn't want `java.lang.String`

Comment: Yes, any API is off limits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below logic,code

```
char charInput[] = new char[]{'A', 'B', 'C'};
for (int i = 0; i < charInput.length; i++) 
{
    char a = charInput[i];
    //This will make your char to lower case if it is in uppercase.
    if(a >=65 && a<= 90)
        a+=32;
    charInput[i] = a;
}
```

So, Basically we will convert array of character in lower case so that you can easily make comparison between both char arrays.

Comment: In numbers, and special characters are not case sensitive. This code will only make uppercase letters to lower case. You don't have to worry about numbers, and special characters. This logic will work for all.

Comment: Will i need to loop through both arrays to convert them both to lower case and then compare?

Comment: Yes, You have to convert both the arrays in lowercase. Then loop for compare both array. So that your all characters will be in lowercase. and you will not face any issue of case sensitive.